# ¿Como pasar un archivo de la carpeta Resources a un File?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Tengo un aechivo .mp3 en la carpeta "app\src\main\res\raw\archivo.mp3" en mi proyecto de Android Studio, y quiero pasarlo a un File(), y luego a un InputStream.
He probado lo siguiente pero me da error:

```
val fileUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+packageName+"/" +R.raw.do_nota)
var file :File = File(fileUri.toString())
val input :InputStream = InputStream(file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas primeramente definir el permiso :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

y requerirlo manualmente:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413660/set-permision-in-kotlin

lo más sencillo para leer un archivo desde /raw es usar el método [openRawResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/Resources#openRawResource(kotlin.Int))

```
 //Obtiene archivo de directorio /raw
 val inputStream:InputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.archivo)
```

---

Este sería un ejemplo el cual obtiene el contenido de un archivo almacenado en el directorio /raw (`R.raw.archivo`) y almacena su contenido en otro archivo en el directorio de almacenamiento externo:

```
   private fun saveFile() {

        try {

            //Define nombre de archivo destino.
            val newFileName = "nuevo_archivo.txt"
            //Define directorio.
            val newFileDir = "/Android/"
            //Obtiene directorio de almacenamiento externo y directorio donde se copiara archivo.
            val path_newFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + newFileDir

            //Obtiene archivo de directorio /raw
            val inputStream:InputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.archivo)
            //Lee contenido de archivo
            val inputString = inputStream.bufferedReader().use{it.readText()}

            //Define y crea archivo
            var myExternalFile:File = File(path_newFileName,newFileName)
            myExternalFile.createNewFile();


            try {
                val fileOutPutStream = FileOutputStream(myExternalFile)
                //Guarda contenido en archivo
                fileOutPutStream.write(inputString.toByteArray())
                fileOutPutStream.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IOException " + e.message)
            }


        } catch (e:Exception){
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception : " + e.toString())
        }

    }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!,  me ha sido muy util. Un saludo.